# How we can deal with long path in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

```
    Dim oDocument As Object
    Dim blnOpen As Boolean = False

    Try
        For Each oDocument In oWord.Documents
            If oDocument.Path.ToLower & "\" & oDocument.Name.ToLower = sFilePath.ToLower Then
                blnOpen = True

                ' If the document is open Return it in an output param
                oDocument.Activate()
                oOutDocument = oDocument
            End If
        Next

        If blnOpen = False Then
            oOutDocument = oWord.Documents.open(sFilePath)
```

I am using this code  but not able to open path which is created by windows powershell, In C# we are using `"\\?\"` to validate path . Is there any way to validate path in VB.Net

Comment: The same method should work in VB.NET. Note that backslashes are not escaped in VB.NET strings, so perhaps that is where it is going wrong.

Comment: Is there any chance of changing to .NET Core? That is supposed to work with long paths (but test first).

Comment: No , I can't do that

Answer (score 0):

In both C# and VB you should probably be using [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) to combine elements into a filesystem path.  So instead of this:

```
oDocument.Path.ToLower & "\" & oDocument.Name.ToLower
```

You'd do this:

```
Path.Combine(oDocument.Path.ToLower, oDocument.Name.ToLower)
```

This lets the host system handle the task of knowing *how* to combine the strings into a valid path for the filesystem.

Comment: oOutDocument = oWord.Documents.open(sFilePath)                                                                                         this Line is opening My word document but I am not able to open by this method when I am using long path . Could you please let me know how to resolve this suitation beacuse in c#  I am using "\\?\" to validate path.

Comment: @manalivarshney: Why are you not able to open the file?  How specifically does it fail?

Comment: If  I am using length less than 248 than I am able to open but If I am using path length is more than that  not able to open

Comment: Any Solutions from anyone.''\\?\" it will work top open document through Vb.Net